# facebook share debbuger error 302

Tags: facebook, share

I'm facing an issue with the facebook share functionality.

I need to share a link to my site but it keeps returning `Error 302 "Moved Temporarily".`

As an example, I'm trying to share the following link   http://www.rb.mcr.pt/webcenter/portal/RedeBibliotecas/Detalhe_Noticia?id=8210

The `og` tags are set correctly and, as far as I can tell, there are no rewrite rules or redirects active on the HTTP server.

Can anyone share some thoughts on the matter?

Edit: The website was built with Oracle Webcenter Portal. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Click “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” in the debug tool output, and you will see that it returns a document saying this was moved to `http://www.rb.mcr.pt:80/webcenter/portal/RedeBibliotecas/Detalhe_Noticia?id=8210` ... so you need to go and find out why your system does this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CBroe. The thing is, that message makes no sense at all. It says the document moved to the same place that it was in in the first place. It only adds the port 80 to the URL. As I said, there is no rewrite rule or redirect in place in my HTTP server. I'm really in the dark here.